# Azure Data Studio, Database Project, Postdeployment scripts

Tags: database-project, azure-data-studio

I am trying to get multiple files into a post-deployment
using project Azure Data Studio

I have a main deployment file `Script.PostDeployment_Main.sql`
Contents
are

```
-- This file contains SQL statements that will be executed after the build script.

:r .\..\Scripts\Script.PostDeployment_IntialSetup.sql
:r .\..\Scripts\Script.PostDeployment_Update.sql
```

I have those 2 files
Located correctly.

```
Script.PostDeployment_Update.sql
```

contains

```
  GO
    UPDATE SDK_Table2 SET [SDK2_Name] = 'SDK2_Table6_U' WHERE SDK2_Name = 'SDK2_Table6';
GO
```

When I run the command line
`dotnent build` I get an error

> C:\ws\PushNotifications-Services\Notifications.AuditDB\DBO\Scripts\Script.PostDeployment
>
> _Update.sql(2,1,2,1): Build error SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context.
> [C:\ws\PushNotifications-Services\Notifications.AuditDB\Notifications.AuditDB.sqlproj]
> C:\ws\PushNotifications-Services\Notifications.AuditDB\DBO\Scripts\Script.PostDeployment
>
> _IntialSetup.sql(41,1,41,1): Build error SQL71006: Only one statement is allowed per batch. A batch separato  r, such as 'GO', might be
> required between statements. [C:\ws\PushNotifications-Services\
> Notifications.AuditDB\Notifications.AuditDB.sqlproj]

I switch between sqlcmd enabled\disabled and click the parse both the IntialSetup and Update file parse correctly
I Do that on _Main.sql and I get the following error

> Failed to parse the query: 1. Incorrect syntax near ':'. 2. Incorrect
> syntax near '.'.